# Drag and Drop over grid and revert back if size is greater than grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

This is my Canvas element:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="280px" height="280px" style="background: #fff;"></canvas>
```

And this is my element section from which i want to drag elements to each grid unit of this canvas.

```
<div id="element1" style="width:55px; height:55px; border: 1px solid; background: lightblue"></div>
<div id="element2" style="width:111px; height:55px; border: 1px solid; background: lightgreen"> 
<div id="element1" style="width:55px; height:55px; border-right: 1px solid"></div>
```

And this is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var bw = 280;
var bh = 280;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.strokeStyle = "black";

function drawGrid() {
    for (var x = 0; x <= bw; x += 56) {
        context.moveTo(x, 0);
        context.lineTo(x, 280);
        context.stroke();
    }
    for (var y = 0; y <= bh; y += 56) {
        context.moveTo(0, y);
        context.lineTo(280, y);
        context.stroke();
    }
}
drawGrid();
</script>
```

Comment: What is the code you have so far? What are you having problems with?

Comment: This is my Canvas element:
<canvas id="canvas" width="280px" height="280px" style="background: #fff;"></canvas>

And this is my element section from which i want to drag elements to each grid unit of this canvas.

<div id="element1" style="width:55px; height:55px; border: 1px solid; background: lightblue"></div>
<div id="element2" style="width:111px; height:55px; border: 1px solid; background: lightgreen"> 
  <div id="element1" style="width:55px; height:55px; border-right: 1px solid"></div>
</div>

Comment: this is script part: <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var bw = 280;
    var bh = 280;

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    function drawGrid(){
    for (var x = 0; x <= bw; x += 56) {
        context.moveTo(x, 0);
        context.lineTo(x,280);  
  context.stroke();
    }


    for (var y = 0; y <= bh; y += 56) {
        context.moveTo(0, y);
        context.lineTo(280,y);
  context.stroke();
    }

    }
    drawGrid();
    </script>

Comment: till now i am only able to generate grids. and i want to achive something like this : http://gojs.net/latest/samples/planogram.html

Comment: You have duplicate ID's.. that is going to cause problems.

Comment: I changed the ids but still facing same issue. What i did till now is that i make #element1 as draggable and i want to drop it to canvas so that it can fit into one grid unit of that canvas. and if its size is greater than that unit it can revert back to original position.

Comment: its getting dragged over canvas but it is not visible.